# C# : Convert datetime from string with different format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

If my string is 26/01/2011 00:14:00
but my computer set United state format (AM:PM)
How to convert my string into `Datetime`?
I try `Convert.ToDateTime()` but it cause error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others have said, you can use DateTime.TryParseExact, but you also seem to have a European culture format in your date. It might not hurt to make an attempt to use that to perform the conversion:

```
CultureInfo enGB = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); 
string dateString;
DateTime dateValue;

// Parse date with no style flags.
dateString = "26/01/2011 00:14:00";
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "g", enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx). If you have to accept multiple possible datetime formats, both of those methods have overloads that take an array of format strings.

As far as that format, it looks like "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss"

Answer (score 0):

I use DateTime.Tryparse - that way you can catch and handle a failure gracefully:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx