# How to convert date to european format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to convert a date to European format and display it in grid view column, can any one tell me how to do this?

This is my code:

```
EventManagerDataContext db = new EventManagerDataContext();

if (txtSearchnews.Text == "")
{
    var q = from a in db.EMR_NEWs

    select new
    {
        News_ID=a.News_ID,
        Title=a.Title,
        Text=a.Text,
        Creation_Date=a.Creation_Date,
        Publication_Date=a.Publication_Date,
        Expiration_Date=a.Expiration_Date
    };
    grid.DataSource = q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to convert. Try to search about formatting data in grid. If you want to change formatting in general, that's Thread.CurrentUICulture. By the way, what grid do you use?

Comment: Take a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796796/c-sharp-convert-datetime-from-string-with-different-format. You can also set cultureinfo

Comment: @Monika In prior, I am living since a couple of years in Europe. But what is the european format from your point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do one thing after reformatting the date write this

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strFormatedDate);
```

where `*strFormatedDate*` is the string variable that holds your formatted date.

now you have both the dates in DateTime format, so go ahead with your functionality.

I hope it will work out!

Answer (score 3):

What you're after is Globalization.

You should check out [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) in .NET.

Using that you can set the culture of your thread to a specific culture, meaning that numbers and dates can be formatted accordingly.

Furthermore, you can access or use [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) or [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) of not only your own culture/current threads culture, but also as objects you can use in various parse and tostring methods.

Understanding those are valurable to being able to do cross-country/cross-format applications, so I can only advice you to look them up and play around whit them.
Then when understanding them more, you'll find many ways to solve your specific issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution like this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
```

and

```
Creation_Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(a.Creation_Date,tzi),
```